# knitr losts accentuated characters when compiled in pdf

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, knitr

I read "all" demands concerning knitr and encoding but I cannot find solution... My problem seems very simple:
Here is my Try.Rnw file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Essai de données}   
<<>>=
a <- "éssaié"
print(a)
@
\end{document}
```

It is saved in UTF-8. When I compile it in Rstudio or directly in R with

```
knit2pdf("Try.Rnw", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I get this pdf:

```
1 Essai de donnes
￼a <- "ssai"
print(a)
```

All the accentuated characters are lost.
Same happened if I save it in LATIN1.

Thanks a lot

Marc

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.1 Patched (2013-06-10 r62935)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8/C/fr_FR.UTF-8/fr_FR.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.1



Information sur le package ‘knitr’

Description :

Package:            knitr
Type:               Package
Title:              A general-purpose package for dynamic report generation in R
Version:            1.2
Date:               2013-04-10
```

Rstudio

```
> versionInfo()
$version
[1] ‘0.98.156’

$mode
[1] "desktop"
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem may come from three possible sources: `knitr`, the encoding, or LaTeX. To diagnose the problem comes from `knitr`, you need to call `knit()` instead of `knit2pdf()` to see if the tex output is correct:

```
library(knitr)
knit("Try.Rnw", encoding = "UTF-8")
# open Try.tex and see if the accentuated characters are there
```

To make sure the encoding is really UTF-8, check the menu `File --> Save with Encoding`.

Comment: I ensure again that encoding was in UTF-8 and I run knit() as you suggest. The accentuated characters are present (see below). So they are lost during LaTeX conversion. Any idea ? Thanks a lot.
\begin{knitrout}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{kframe}
\begin{alltt}
a <- \hlstring{"éssaié"}
\hlfunctioncall{print}(a)
\end{alltt}
\begin{verbatim}
## [1] "éssaié"
\end{verbatim}
\end{kframe}
\end{knitrout}

Comment: @user1847608 So `knitr` is not the culprit here; it is a problem of `pdflatex`; I cannot reproduce it using TeXLive 2012 under Ubuntu 13.04. Presumably you are using MacTeX?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem now. All works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your great work. It renders our life more easy. Marc